# Are the sun rays incident on earth's surface parallel to good approximation?

Tags: geometric-optics, sun, estimation

If so how can an image of the sun be formed using a pinhole camera (for e.g. sun diameter estimate), the rays incident on the pinhole can't all be parallel and at least for this case the approximation si not valid, right ?

Comment: Ok, I have edited the question to be more straightforward type now.

Comment: I think the title's improved, but the first version wasn't a list question - it was perfectly acceptable by the rules of this site. Anyhow, you have a good answer already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different senses in which the rays from the Sun are "not exactly" parallel, and one of these is a better approximation than the other.

- The rays traveling from *different* points on the Sun's surface to the *same* point on Earth's surface are not precisely parallel.  In fact, the angle between them is simply the angular size of the Sun, or about 0.5°.  (This number can be found by taking the ratio of the Sun's diameter to the Earth-Sun distance.)  This is what makes it possible for a lens or a pinhole to form an image.
- The rays traveling from the *same* point on the Sun to *different* points on the Earth are not precisely parallel either.  However, the angle between them is much, much smaller.  For example, the rays hitting the opposite sides of a lens with diameter 10 cm differ in angle by
  $$
  \theta \approx \frac{\text{diameter of lens}}{\text{Earth-Sun distance}} = \frac{ 10 \text{ cm}}{150 \text{ million km}} = 6.7 \times 10^{-13} \text{ radians} = 4 \times 10^{-11} \text{ degrees}.
  $$

When solving geometric optics problems, the rays from an "object at infinity" are usually assumed to be parallel in the second sense, which as you can see is a pretty good approximation.